# What table fields would I need here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, field

I want to create a commenting model with a twist. I want there to be multiple commenting columns like on hunch.com, except that a user can decide how many columns there should be. Also, a user can decide the title for each column.

This is rather dynamic, so how would I set up my tables for this?

Comment: You might want to add more detail for those of us that are unfamiliar with hunch.com.

Comment: it's very simple to sign into hunch.com

Comment: My god, I just wasted the last 15 minutes taking that survey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot really change the attributes of a model, if you want to create dynamic model attributes, you can have 3 models :

```
User
Attribute
UserAttribute
```

Now, you can add as many attributes are you want (Attribute is the static representation of an attribute). Then, a user can have many attributes through user_attributes.

Comment: ahh, so if videos have comments, then I would do a has_many through association between videos and comments with videoscomments as the independent model?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. And you can store extra information on the VideoComment model.

Comment: You can just do a user has many comments through video_comments. Then, you can do a user.video_comments and get video + comments for a user.

Comment: ok now let's say I want a video to have many commentColumns, and each commentColumn to have many comments, and each comment to belong to a user. How would that work out? This is starting to get rather complex :/

Comment: Would I just make video_comments have 4 extra fields for the 4 columns that may be there?

Comment: You would just need to break down the comment model so that a comment has many comment_columns. Then, you would be able to do user.comment.comment_columns

Comment: Ahhhh, ok so just to sum it up, you have videoComments in the center of User, Video, and Comment, and then comment columns which is a has many belongs to association with Comment?

Comment: by the way, do you have a twitter?

Comment: ok so user.comments.comment_columns would be all of the users comments, and how would you get that user's comments for a specific video?

Comment: user.videos.comments would give you that if user has many videos and videos have many comments.

Comment: @SpyrosP I have some questions about that if you have the time: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/633/ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect use case for NoSQL. I'd use something like CouchDB or Mongo here. Since there you don't have a schema you can add the attributes as needed.